# What does "isRtlSupported && 1" mean?

Tags: layout, integer, boolean

In ConstraintLayout , there is some codes written below:

```
protected boolean isRtl() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        boolean isRtlSupported = (this.getContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & 4194304) != 0;
        return isRtlSupported && 1 == this.getLayoutDirection();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I copy this to my custom layout, Android Studio cannot read the "1" in && 1 .
Why a boolean can && a int ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it should be read as follows

```
return isRtlSupported && (1 == this.getLayoutDirection());
```

Here 1 is replaced by View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL works fine.
i.e.

```
return isRtlSupported && (View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL == this.getLayoutDirection());
```

where

```
public static final int LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL = LayoutDirection.RTL;
```

in View.java

and

```
public static final int RTL = 1;
```

in LayoutDirection.java